# post login method for token retrieval . postman test renders 500 internal server error

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I'm working on a post login method through restful api using Symfony this is my code :

```
 /**
 * @Rest\View()
 * @Rest\Post("/login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
     $username = $request->request->get('username');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');

    if(is_null($username) || is_null($password)) {
        return new Response(
          'Please verify all your inputs.',
          Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
          array('Content-type' => 'application/json')
        );
    }

    $user_manager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

    $user = $user_manager->findUserByUsername($username);

     if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }


    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $salt = $user->getSalt();

    if($encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $salt)) {


  $token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder')
        ->encode([
            'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            'exp' => time() + 3600 // 1 hour expiration
        ]);

    } else {
        $response = new Response(
          'Username or Password not valid.',
          Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
          array('Content-type' => 'application/json')
        );
    }


        return new JsonResponse(['token' => $token]);
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve a token using the jwt authentication bundle  to store it in localstorage on angularjs frontend and send it with each request made  by the user.
The problem is when i test the rest method using postman it renders a 500 error and nothing more . Could someone please help me figure out where the error might be espacially that the error rendered is quite brief and unclear.i 've spent the last 4 hours searching but no solution was found.

Comment: Nothing in your logs? In cases like these I usually resort to stepping through the code in my debugger. The issue may be in something this method calls, and not in the method itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. i checked the logs and i found the error .